# How do i map an array of two objects in javascript based on a currentTime(time it was clicked) column

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I have two objects in my localstorage, for each article or podcast being clicked, 
every time either is clicked, i add it with id and current time to its object, i want to show them in one history screen based on the time they were added. i really need help, i have spent weeks trying to solve this but couldn't get it right

below are the objects in my localStorage

`var { articlesInHistory, podcastsInHistory } = this.props.stores.appStore;`

And below is structure

```
Array [

  articlesInHistory {
    "currentTime": 1585439646,
    "id": "156701",
    "currentTime": 15854396345,
    "id": "156201",
},

podcastsInHistory {
    "currentTime": 15854234,
    "id": "4",
    "currentTime": 15854394543,
    "id": "34",
}
]
```

And here are the original objects from Database

`var { articles, podcasts } = this.props.stores.appStore;`

components to be displayed are below
Articles
`<PodcastList navigate={navigate} podcast={podcast} key={id} />)`

Podcasts
`<SmallArticle key={id} article={article} />`

I want to show two different components based on the currentTime column ORDER, 
if article was added first than add it or if podcast was added first then push podcast component. i do not want articles on top and podcast bottom, i want them mixed in time/visit order.

Example:

```
if articlesInHistory.time >  podcastsInHistory.time
  data.push(<SmallArticle key={id} article={article} />)
else if podcastsInHistory.time >  articlesInHistory.time
  data.push(<PodcastList key={id} article={article} />)
```

Comment: the data are broken, can u clean up.

Comment: @xdeepakv i cleaned up man

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below sample, You can update data accordingly.

**Sandbox:**https://codesandbox.io/s/articlepodcast-wd2rv

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./app.css";

function Todo(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    articlesInHistory: [
      {
        currentTime: 1585439646,
        title: "Article1",
        id: "156701"
      }
    ],
    podcastsInHistory: [
      {
        currentTime: 15854234,
        title: "podcast 2",
        id: "34"
      },
      {
        currentTime: 15854234,
        title: "podcast 1",
        id: "33"
      }
    ]
  });
  const mappedData = useMemo(
    () =>
      []
        .concat(
          state.articlesInHistory.map(x => {
            x.type = "article";
            return x;
          })
        )
        .concat(
          state.podcastsInHistory.map(x => {
            x.type = "podcasts";
            return x;
          })
        )
        .sort((item1, item2) => item1.currentTime - item2.currentTime),
    [state.articlesInHistory, state.podcastsInHistory]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {mappedData.map(item => {
        if (item.type === "article") return <Article data={item} />;
        return <Podcast data={item} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
function Article({ data }) {
  return (
    <div className="article">
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
function Podcast({ data }) {
  return (
    <div className="podcast">
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: thank you man, i will try it now and i will get back to you now

Comment: can i sent you my file? its react native.

Comment: I added a file named History.js

Comment: I can see the components are showing with empty data, will just update them, thank you man.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/articlepodcast-ejopz?file=/History.js